# Add a new page after all pages that contains specific text in Word document

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

I need to add a blank page after all pages containing a specifc word like "S U M M A R Y             ".

```
Sub SelFind()
    Dim oRng As Range
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
    With oRng.Find
        .Text = "S U M M A R Y             "
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Page"
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
    End With
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

This is doing it for a single page. How can I loop through all the pages.

Comment: Use the Code in the Answer, Simple `Do` loop will work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Simple Do Loop will work for you:

```
Sub SelFind()


   ActiveDocument.Range.Select

    Do

    With Selection.Find
            .Text = "S U M M A R Y             "
            .Execute
    End With

        If Selection.Find.Found Then

            Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Page"
            Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
            Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak

        Else: GoTo nxt

        End If
    Loop

nxt:

ActiveDocument.Range.Select

    Do

    With Selection.Find
            .Text = "R O Y A L T Y             "
            .Execute
    End With

        If Selection.Find.Found Then
        Dim Rnddg As Integer
            Rnddg = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)

            If Rnddg Mod 2 > 0 Then
                Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Section"
                Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
                Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
                Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
            End If

        Else: Exit Sub

        End If
    Loop



End Sub
```

Comment: @Mikku, the issue is we are able to get the starting page of the "Royalty" but we should have to get the ending page number. and then have to verify if it is even or odd and add a blank page.

Comment: @RamSingh ... It should find all the occurrences .. as we are starting an entirely new loop.  I would suggest that you post a new question if it's not working now.

Comment: @RamSingh .. Post a new Question ... I will answer there.

Comment: Please check this question 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647726/insert-blank-if-section-ends-on-odd-page-word-macro

Answer (score 0):

You might try something based on:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "S U M M A R Y             "
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    Set Rng = .Duplicate
    Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber))
    Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Page")
    Rng.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertAfter Chr(12) & Chr(12)
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: it adds the blank page but with first line text of next page's text.

Comment: The issue comes down to how you want to define this blank page. Plus you haven't told us what's already at the end of the pages concerned. You could change Chr(12) to Chr(12) & Chr(12). code edited