# need to skip the line that contains the text Word Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to print documents and what it requires is:

1. Sumarry page should print on single page(always a single page actually) but the next page gets printed over it's back i.e. royalty Summary. so we added a blank page after every Summary page using Macro.
2. If "Royalty" is ending on a Odd number(example starting at page number 2 and ending on 3 means total 3 pages), then need to add a empty page. So the next summary section will start printing on a new page not at the back of ending page.

what i have write till now is as below:

```
Sub Test()


InsertSectionBreaks "S U M M A R Y             "
  InsertSectionBreaks "R O Y A L T Y             "
End Sub

Sub InsertSectionBreaks(FindText As String)
  Dim FindRange As Word.Range, SectionRange As Word.Range
  Dim Found As Boolean

  Set FindRange = ActiveDocument.Content

  ' Find next section based on text, insert odd page section break just before
  FindRange.Find.ClearFormatting
  With FindRange.Find
    .Text = FindText
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    Found = .Execute
  End With

  Do While Found
    'avoid adding a section break at beginning of document
    If FindRange.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) > 1 Then
      Set SectionRange = FindRange.Duplicate
      SectionRange.Collapse wdCollapseStart
      SectionRange.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakOddPage
    End If
    FindRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Found = FindRange.Find.Execute
  Loop
End Sub
```

It works fine, but the company name i have in same line before the "Summary" or "Royalty" gets on the blank page. here is the pic of the output i am getting:

[image: Output of above Macro]

I'm not getting how this can be fixed, company name should remain on same page. should include blank page in between. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the correct page break to start next page on an odd or even page and you will need no macro to add blank pages.

[image]

Comment: I need to do it using Macro.

Comment: @RamSingh Then add one of these even/odd specific page breaks with macro. Use the macro recorder to find out the code that is used for that. Note that you don't need to check if "Royalty" is ending on a odd number or not. The page break will handle it correctly anyway. Also I think you can add them permanently to your document (without macro)